# Django: Best way to highlight primary/favorite relation in ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

What is the best way to highlight a specific relationship in a ManyToMany relationship in django?

For instance, if I want to highlight the primary or otherwise "best" reference to a gene in a database of genes, my current strategy (which seems somehow wrong and repetitive) is to use a foreign key in addition to a ManyToManyField:

```
from django.db import models

class Gene(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    primary_reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference)
    other_references = models.ManyToManyField(Reference)  # doesn't include primary

class Reference(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField()
    author = models.CharField()
```

this gets the job done, but now if I want to get ALL references, I can't just get `gene.references` ... (rather, I need to concatenate `primary_references` and `other_references`)

on the other hand, if I were to just make a single ManyToManyField field

```
class Gene(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    referencess = models.ManyToManyField(Reference)  # includes primary
```

what is the best way to get something like `gene.primary_reference` (and conversely, `gene.other_references`, excluding the primary)?

I thought of having an additional field in the Reference model with something like a boolean for "primary reference"... but that doesn't work because as an additional note to my case: a given reference can reference *many* genes while being the primary reference for only *one* of its referenced genes.

I should also point out the the criteria determining the "primary" reference in this case is not something that can be calculated from information in the reference model (such as date published, for example).

Comment: Is primary_reference supposed to be a singular ForeignKey as you have in the code example? If so, what you have here is fine, it shouldn't be too hard to exclude that single reference if you are looking only for non-primary references. If there's a possibility of multiple primary references, then that's a different question (answered through `related_through`).

Comment: Yes, there will only ever be a single primary_reference.  So having both a foreignKey and ManyToMany relation to the same model is not considered bad practice?  And would the best way to get all references be something like 
    `@property
    def all_references:`?

Comment: Personally, I'd have the `ManyToMany` point to all references, including the primary reference. If you want *only* the non-primary references, then you can either construct a query like this: `gene.references.exclude(id=gene.primary_reference_id)`

Comment: @michaelb: Consider writing that up as an answer, with perhaps a little more detail, and get the credit you deserve.

Comment: tlambert: you're welcome, added as answer.

@aliteralmind thanks for the tip, still learning the ropes here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you have it is fine, the only thing I'd change is have two fields: `references` (for all references) and `primary_reference`. For example:

```
class Gene(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    primary_reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference, related_name="primary_reference")
    references = models.ManyToManyField(Reference)

class Reference(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField()
    author = models.CharField()
```

If you want to query only the non-primary references, then you can construct a query like this:

```
 gene.references.exclude(id=gene.primary_reference_id)
```

If there can be more than one `primary_reference` then you'll want to use [Django's `related_through` feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to add, essentially, "meta-data" to the relationship itself.

Comment: If I may ask a related question: what if the gene->reference was instead a OneToMany reference (every reference referred to one and only one gene)?  That would set up a situation with reciprocal foreign keys... in which `class Gene` has a `ForeignKey(Reference)` and `class Reference` has a `ForeignKey(Gene)`... Is that acceptable? Is there a better strategy?